# SNS GetEndpointAttributes & Publish to Endpoint not available in .Net SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using v2.5.26.2, Runtime version v2.0.50727 of the AWS SDK for .NET and noticed that GetEndpointAttributes calls is not available from the SNS Client, nor can you target an endpoint Arn in the Publish Request message.

The documentation for the APi, [GetEndpointAttributes Method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html) ,for SNS indicates that you should be able to do both of those things.

I tired asking this question on the [Aws Support Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=143963&tstart=0) to figure out why this call was not available but have yet to receive a reply more than a week later.

I also tried several web searches for this problem to no avail.

Is the a limitation of the .Net SDK or perhaps just a limitation of the version I am using? 
If so, is there a workaround to make either of these calls.

**Edit: Code Samples as requested (although not much to show since objects are not getting recognized**

**GetEndpointAttributes**

So according to the [Amazon Documentation for a GetEndpointAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html) first we need to create a class that derives from the virtual class GetEndpointAttributes like so.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;

namespace Company.Project.Sns
{
     public class SnsGetEndpointAttributes : GetEndpointAttributes
     {

     }
}
```

**Which creates the following compiler error**

The type or namespace name 'GetEndpointAttributes' could not be found

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko added what little code I could since objects cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get all the endpoints subscribed to your application making a request using its ARN. The response contains a collection from all the endpoints and their attributes, then you can search for the match and retrieve its attributes:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetEndpointAttributes(string platformArn, string endpointArn)
    {
        var listPlatformEndpointsRequest = new ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest();
        listPlatformEndpointsRequest.PlatformApplicationArn = platformArn;
        var response = SnsClient.ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication(listPlatformEndpointsRequest);
        Dictionary<string, string> endpointAttributes = response.Endpoints.Exists(x => x.EndpointArn.Equals(endpointArn))
            ? response.Endpoints.Find(x => x.EndpointArn.Equals(endpointArn)).Attributes
            : null;
        return endpointAttributes;
    }
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you can't target the endpoint ARN, because every time you subscribe an endpoint you should be storing the ARN inside a DB or something like that. Anyway, here is a sample to publish a message if you can access your endpoint ARN:

```
public void SendMessage(string endpointArn, string message)
    {
        var request = new PublishRequest();
        request.Message = message;
        request.TargetArn = endpointArn;

        var response = SnsClient.Publish(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Hope this help you.